# Merge multiple columns in pandas but move old column headers to align with the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multiple-columns

I am using Pandas on csv files and am trying to find code to get a large data set where we are describing the temperatures on each floor and trying to distinguish our locations and floor numbers.
What I have now is

| Building | Floor 1 Temp | Floor 3 Temp | Floor 5 Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G | 60.370 | 70.869 | 56.784 |
| H | 43.57 | 54 | 65.5 |

to:

| Building | Floor | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G | 1 | 60.370 |
| G | 3 | 70.869 |
| G | 5 | 56.784 |
| H | 1 | 43.57 |
| H | 3 | 54.0 |
| H | 5 | 65.5 |

I am good on making my csv into a df but can't figure out how to merge the temperature column while keeping the data organized. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), and then only keep numerical values for the `Floor` column by using `.str.replace('\D+', '', regex=True)`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='Building', var_name='Floor', value_name='Temp').sort_values('Building')
df['Floor'] = df['Floor'].str.replace('\D+', '', regex=True)
df
Out[1]: 
  Building Floor    Temp
0        G     1  60.370
2        G     3  70.869
4        G     5  56.784
1        H     1  43.570
3        H     3  54.000
5        H     5  65.500
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to maintain the order of `Building` without sorting, as follows:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Building').stack().rename_axis(['Building', 'Floor']).reset_index(name='Temp')
df1['Floor'] = df1['Floor'].str.split(' ').str[1]

print(df1)



  Building Floor    Temp
0        G     1   60.37
1        G     3  70.869
2        G     5  56.784
3        H     1   43.57
4        H     3      54
5        H     5    65.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to reshape the data:

```
df.pivot_longer(index='Building', 
                names_to = ('Floor', '.value'), 
                names_pattern = r".+(\d)\s(.+)",
                sort_by_appearance = True)
 
  Building Floor    Temp
0        G     1  60.370
1        G     3  70.869
2        G     5  56.784
3        H     1  43.570
4        H     3  54.000
5        H     5  65.500
```

The `.value` pairs with `Temp` and keeps that as a column name, while any data not associated with `.value` is passed into the `Floor` column. The data association is done via the `names_pattern` argument, which is a regular expression.

You could achieve the same thing with [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), with a bit of massaging:

```
step1 = [ent.split() for ent in df]
step2 = [ent[::-1][:-1] if 'Floor' in ent else ent for ent in step1]
step3 = map("_".join, step2)
df.columns = [*step3]

df
 
  Building  Temp_1  Temp_3  Temp_5
0        G   60.37  70.869  56.784
1        H   43.57  54.000  65.500

pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames='Temp', 
                i='Building', 
                j='Floor', 
                sep="_").reset_index()
 
  Building  Floor    Temp
0        G      1  60.370
1        H      1  43.570
2        G      3  70.869
3        H      3  54.000
4        G      5  56.784
5        H      5  65.500
```